# Unable to resove ./SafeAreaContext in expo

Tags: react-native, npm, expo

While running expo start this message shows up.

Unable to resolve "./SafeAreaContext" from "node_modules\react-native-safe-area-context\src\index.tsx"

Answer (score 1):

try updating your expo CLI to latest by running npm install -g expo-cli. You can also install safe-area by running yarn add react-native-safe-area-context.